# java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: OffsetSeconds

Tags: date, exception, java-8, instant, localdatetime

I am using the following functional Interface to make a general purpose custom date format converter.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CustomDateFormatterInterface {
String convertStringToDate();
}
```

The Implementation of this functional Interface is as follows

```
CustomDateFormatterInterface customDateFormatterInterface = () -> {
                LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                        .withLocale(Locale.getDefault())
                        .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

                Instant now = Instant.now();

                String formatted = dateTimeFormatter.format(localDateTime);
                LocalDateTime parsed = dateTimeFormatter.parse(formatted, LocalDateTime::from);
                return parsed.toString();
            };
```

I want to get the following date format
`2011-04-27T19:07:36+0000`. But I am getting an exception. If I try to use the `now` Instant I am getting the output as

```
2020-12-29T15:44:34Z
```

What should I do can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Let me know for any other things if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) which has offset of the timezone and truncate it to seconds

> A date-time with an offset from UTC/Greenwich in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00.

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));

offsetDateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME); //2020-12-29T18:28:44+01:00
```

If you want a custom format the build it using [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html)

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .appendOffset("+HHMM", "+0000")
            .toFormatter();
offsetDateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).format(dateTimeFormatter); //2020-12-29T17:36:51+0000
```

Comment: this is giving the output as ```2020-12-30T09:52:05.082Z``` but I need the output like ```2020-12-29T17:36:51+0000```

Comment: Hey I figured out a way to do it. Using OffsetDateTIme. Thanks